# How to identify that Process is complete now, end close this event OutputDataReceived in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using `Process` of C# for open `cmd` and fire command. After completion of this process I want to use List which one is filled by `OutputDataReceived` for further use.

But, i couldn't be able to identify that `Process` is completes now and you can use List.

I'm getting this error. `collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute`

**Code**

```
        String exeFileName = "cmd";
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(exeFileName);

        info.Arguments = @"/c myCommand";

        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        info.RedirectStandardError = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;

        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo = info;

        // Set our event handler to asynchronously read the sort output.
        proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_OutputDataReceived);
        proc.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_ErrorDataReceived);

        try
        {

            proc.Start();
            proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
            // i don't want to pass some time interval here like WaitForExit(1000)
            // cause command takes dynamic time
            proc.WaitForExit(); 
            if (!proc.HasExited)
            {
                proc.Kill();
            }

            // this throws error like "collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute"
            foreach(i in list)
            {
                //logic
            }               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    static void proc_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
           // logic
           list.Add(e.data);
        }
    }

    static void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
       // logic
       list.Add(e.data);
    }
```

Comment: Use a for loop, not foreach.. especially if deleting work backwards..

Comment: You could try to wait for the Process Exited Event, but I can't see how your list can be changed by the error and data received eventhandlers after the process has exited. When WaitForExit returns the process has exited. Except maybe you are starting a further Process subsequently in your initial process and you are not waiting for it to return.

Comment: What are you doing in your //logic? Are you adding / removing items to/from the list you are working on? If yes: Try putting the added Items to a "newitems" list and the ones to delete to an "itemsToDelete" list. After you have finished the first foreach(i in list) loop over "newItems" and over "itemsToDelete" and add / remove them from your initial list.

Comment: Thanks! @ThomasVoß, While foreach loop is started even  after that  handler "OutputDataReceived" is getting called. so, it's added items in list.
Alternet solution is this Process.WaitForExit(1000 * 60 * 5) but i couldn't know how much time to wait or how i will know that process is finished.

Comment: The Process.WaitForExit(1000 * 60 * 5) shouldn't work anyway for your solution, as it's not a fixed time it will wait. It will return earlier, if your Process exits. If not it will exit latest after the waiting time even if the process is still running.